# Canon EF 50 mm 1.8 STM - is my lens normal?

Tags: canon, prime, 50mm, build-quality

I recently got a Canon EF 50 mm 1.8 STM for my 250D.
The unit is brand new and it was purchased online.

Inspecting it, I noticed something strange inside the first ring behind the front lens (probably this ring has a name…). It seems like this ring is geometrically cut in several places. The “segments” are equally distributed and they form a pattern.

Please see attached photos.

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

Is this normal, or it is just my unit with a build defect / broken part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My copy of Canon EF 50 mm 1.8 STM is pretty old. But I see the same marks inside. For me it seems like mechanical thing, intended to tighten the elements inside.

Comment: Same thing on my fairly recent one.

Comment: Thank you both for reassuring me! I've never seen this kind of mechanical design inside a lens and I was worried. Have a nice day :)